# CachedRowSet failed to insert row

Tags: java, jdbc, cachedrowset

I'm using `CachedRowSet`. But when I call the `insertRow()` method, there is a `SQLException` failed to insert row.

Here is my code:

```
static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javapos";
static final String USERNAME = "root";
static final String PASSWORD = "sbc";

public static void main (String [] agr) throws SQLException
{
    CachedRowSetImpl rs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    rs.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
    rs.setUsername(USERNAME);
    rs.setPassword(PASSWORD);

    rs.setCommand("select * from uom order by itemid");
    rs.execute();

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString("itemid") + "  -  " + rs.getString("uom"));
    }

    rs.moveToInsertRow();
    rs.updateString(2,"Sample code");
    rs.insertRow();
    rs.moveToCurrentRow();

    rs.acceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please include error stack trace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Failed on insert row
 at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.insertRow(CachedRowSetImpl.java:5449)
 at purchases.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:39)
Java Result: 1

Comment: There should be more info than that.

Comment: except from System.out.prinln, that's the only error stack trace appeared

Comment: Please include the **full** stacktrace in the question itself.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this. I am currently looking for the cause and a potential solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `insertRow()`, the Reference Implementation of `CachedRowSet` performs a check if all required columns have been populated and otherwise it throws an exception (source from [Grepcode `CachedRowSet.insertRow()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java#5451), line numbers don't exactly match):

```
if (onInsertRow == false ||
        insertRow.isCompleteRow(RowSetMD) == false) {
    throw new SQLException(resBundle.handleGetObject("cachedrowsetimpl.failedins").toString());
}
```

The check is performed in [`InsertRow.isCompleteRow(RowSetMetaData)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/com/sun/rowset/internal/InsertRow.java#InsertRow.isCompleteRow%28javax.sql.RowSetMetaData%29):

```
public boolean isCompleteRow(RowSetMetaData RowSetMD) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        if (colsInserted.get(i) == false &&
                RowSetMD.isNullable(i + 1) == ResultSetMetaData.columnNoNulls) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In other words, when inserting a row you **must** provide a value for all columns that are not nullable (this includes the primary key). There seem to be two ways to work around this:

- Setting a (random) value. This does require that your primary key is always generated (even if a value is provided).
- Explicitly setting the column to `null` using `updateNull`. Using `setNull` doesn't work: it provides the same error, and using `setObject(idx, null)` results in a `NullPointerException`

When using your code with these changes I get an `SQLException` when calling `acceptChanges` as the implementation doesn't disable `autoCommit` (it seems to have been [commented out](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/com/sun/rowset/internal/CachedRowSetWriter.java#290)), but it does explicitly call `commit` (which is invalid when in `autoCommit`). This doesn't seem to be easy to solve, except maybe explicitly providing a connection on `execute`, or creating your own implementation.

I think these kind of issues actually demonstrate how little the `RowSet` implementations are actually used (otherwise they would already have been flushed out long ago).

Note however that if this were the actual code you needed and don't need the disconnected characteristics of the `CachedRowSet`, then you could simply use an updatable result set.

Comment: The solution is to provide a connection in non-auto commit mode to `acceptConnection()`, or to so configure its connection or its DataSource if that's what you're using. I agree about the lack of use, I've found several other oddities and bugs. Nobody seems to use this at all. Pity really, there are some good ideas in there. I'm going to open a documentation bug report on it.

Comment: updateNull() works with auto incrementing primary key

Comment: @Don That is the second point I list under _"There seem to be two ways to work around this"_.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```java
        beginAddRow(crs);
        crs.updateString("TABLE_TYPE", "TABLE");
        
        continueAddRow();
        crs.updateString("TABLE_TYPE", "INDEX");
        endAddRow();
```

```java
    static public CachedRowSet beginAddRow(CachedRowSet crs) throws SQLException {
        crs.moveToInsertRow(); // onInsertRow = true
        return crs;
    }

    static public CachedRowSet continueAddRow(CachedRowSet crs) throws SQLException {
        crs.insertRow();
        crs.moveToCurrentRow();
        crs.moveToInsertRow();
        return crs;
    }

    static public CachedRowSet endAddRow(CachedRowSet crs) throws SQLException {
        crs.insertRow();
        crs.moveToCurrentRow(); // onInsertRow = false;
        crs.beforeFirst();
        return crs;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Usually answers based only on code are deleted. It would be good if you can comment your code and explain why it solves the problem. Can be obvious for you, but maybe not for other readers