# what is the equivalent of ado.net datatable in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, datatable

> Dim ConnectionStr As string = "database=InvertedSoftware;server=
>   InvertedSoftware"
>
> Dim objConnection As SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr)
>
> Dim categoryDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter()
>
> categoryDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Category")
>
> objConnection.Open()
>
> Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM
>   tbl_category", objConnection)
>
> objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
>
> categoryDataAdapter.SelectCommand = objCommand
>
> Dim objDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("Inventory")
>
> categoryDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340283/datatable-equivalent-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataSet class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194971/dataset-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent of a `DataTable` in JDBC. The closest thing is probably the [`CachedRowSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html).

Comment: but when i tried CachedRowset, there is SQLException in insertRow() method. Failed to insert row. what is the reason why it's failed to insert new row in CachedRowset? (not yet call acceptchanges() method)

Comment: @ram That is impossible to answer. I suggest you post a new question with code to reproduce and the full error message and stacktrace. In most cases you need to configure the `CachedRowSet` so it is able to persist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819496/java-cachedrowset-failed-to-insert-row -- this is my previous post, thanks in advance @Mark Rotteveel